# Is there a way to import all directory's modules easier than I've done?

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules

There was a simple way of using require

```
readdirSync('./routes')
.map((r)=>app.use('/api', require(.routes/${r})))
```

There's my solution for the import

```
readdirSync('./routes')
.map((r) => import(`./routes/${r}`).then(value => app.use('/api', Object.entries(value).map(entry => entry[1]))))
```

And it seems to be far too complicated. Is there a way to simplify it?